# Is FullCalendar parsing timezones incorrectly?

Tags: timezone, fullcalendar

From firebug:

```
>>> jQuery.fullCalendar.parseISO8601("2011-04-18T17:00:00Z").getUTCHours()
22
```

Shouldn't the result be 17?

parseISO8601 returns this date object:

```
>>> jQuery.fullCalendar.parseISO8601("2011-04-18T17:00:00Z")
Date {Mon Apr 18 2011 17:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)}
```

I think the date object should be "12:00:00 GMT-0500" to be the same time.  Am I misunderstanding it?

From FF 4's Date object:

```
>>> new Date("2011-04-18T17:00:00Z")
Date {Mon Apr 18 2011 12:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)}
>>> new Date("2011-04-18T17:00:00Z").getUTCHours()
17
```

Comment: >>> jQuery.fullCalendar.parseISO8601("2011-04-18T17:00:00Z", false).getUTCHours()
22
>>> jQuery.fullCalendar.parseISO8601("2011-04-18T17:00:00Z", true).getUTCHours()
22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are experiencing this issue:
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=750

will get it fixed soon